# Translation issue : validation failed for item

Tags: 2013, translation-manager

I am facing one translation issue, once I sent a component for translation I got a issue "validation failed for item..." This issue is only replicate on QA CMS with the same component its works fine on Dev CMS.

```
Translation Job id: 28
Translation Job title: XXXX
Source Publication URI: tcm:0-31-1
Source Publication title: XXXX
Source Item URI: tcm:31-3323

Validation failed for item "XXXX" (tcm:31-3323)

------

Source Publication URI: tcm:0-31-1
Source Publication title: 020 XXXX

XML validation error. Reason: The element 'secondaryCallToAction' in namespace 'uuid:172ff43f-fd64-4308-b986-b1109e8ed0cb' has invalid child element 'link' in namespace 'uuid:172ff43f-fd64-4308-b986-b1109e8ed0cb'. List of possible elements expected: 'linkText' in namespace 'uuid:172ff43f-fd64-4308-b986-b1109e8ed0cb'.


Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService.ValidateXml(IdentifiableObjectData data)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.SendForTranslationTask.<ProcessClientBasedOnIts>d__3b.MoveNext()
```

here is the screenshot about the issue

Translation Job

[image]

Error Details

[image]

FYI. This component has embedded schema which has mandatory field but this field doesn't have any set values in the content component.

I also compared the CMS settings between Dev and QA and found out that both are having same settings.

This issue is replicate on Sdl Trdion 2013 SP1 that had also applied [hotfix 88281](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-A18BA5AB-3611-433B-9822-1A9B53F8AE25)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tridion is validating the content against the schema before working on it and sending it off to the Translation Service (otherwise it would have no chance of being returned and checked-in anyway).

In...

> List of possible elements expected: 'linkText' in namespace 'uuid:172ff43f-fd64-4308-b986-b1109e8ed0cb'

You're being told that a field hasn't been populated (or doesn't exist in the component XML) and it should.

Confirm the schema setup is exactly the same in both environments (same fields marked as Translatable, same type of fields, same mandatory/optional selections).

Is 'uuid:172ff43f-fd64-4308-b986-b1109e8ed0cb' is the namespace for an embedded schema?

If it is,

1. is the embedded schema mandatory?
2. is the linkText field mandatory?
3. is the linkText populated? are any other fields in the embedded
4. element populated?

Depending on the answers to the above tests I would try:

- Confirm you have the same SPs and Hotfixes in both environments *(I
  see you've tagged this 2013 and not SP1?)*
- Confirm it is the embedded
  schema

  a. populate the mandatory field(s) in the embedded schema
  b. make all fields optional and leave empty

If it is the embeddable schema then there is a hotfix for this (I'll dig out the reference later) - otherwise reach out to SDL Support directly.

Comment: The Hotfix is TT87682 _TT87682: Error sending items to translation if the contain an optional Embedded Schema with mandatory values._     Note that this is included in the TM Rollup TT88257 which you would be best advised to add.

Comment: @mark here is the answer your question : is the embedded schema mandatory? - No
is the linkText field mandatory? - Yes
is the linkText populated? are any other fields in the embedded -No
element populated? - No

Answer (score 4):

The fix was to install the Translation Manager cumulative hotfix TT88257, as suggested by Mark Saunders. This is also included in the Hotfix rollup 1 for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1, so upgrading to HR1 would also fix this issue.

Interestingly, we were only seeing this issue on our QA, not DEV. The reason for this was that SDL Tridion SP1 HR1 was installed only on DEV. We’d checked the “about” page of our DEV CM and it stated SDL Tridion SP1, so this made us think that HR1 was not installed and sent us down a different path of investigation. Comparing the Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.dll version made us realise that HR1 actually was installed and led to the resolution.

Our learning from this was to check the specific DLL details to confirm the version you’re working with.